# いただきました　vs　くださいました

Tags: translation

I understand いただきました is used when the speaker receives from a giver with a higher status and is くださいました used when a higher-status person gives the speaker something. It makes sense in Japanese sentences. When I google translate the following two sentences, the English translation means the same. Is the translation correct or am I just confused? Pls help.

先生に旅行の写真をみせていただきました -> My teacher showed me some photos from the trip.
先生が旅行の写真をみせてくださいました-> The teacher showed us photos from the trip.

Comment: Google translate is not perfect, especially translating between Japanese and English. The two sentences mostly mean the same thing; the differences in the English you are seeing is because Google is randomly inferring the omitted subject different for the two sentences (I.E. it's guessing who the photos where showed to).

Comment: thank u Mindful

Answer (score 1):

IMO both say the same thing but the latter is slightly more archaic (or elegant, depending on your perspective).

頂く (hold up) does refer to the act by the receiver, and 下さる (give it down) refers to the act by the giver but IMO the fact being conveyed are identical.